# copying the data from formulated column in Excell?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have three columns in MS Excell. The columns are A1,B1,C1. C1 is calculated  automatically based on formula. The formula defined for C1 is(=A1+B1). I mean C1 is the sum of A1 and B1. Now the problem is I wanted to copy the value of C1 to A1 and want to make the B1 column filled with 0.

The moment i try to copy C1 and paste it into A1 the A1 is displaying as "#href" something like this. so how do i copy the value of C1(without Formula) and then paste it to A1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy from C1 in A1 Excel is trying to insert in A1 the same formula contained in C1 with your relative addresses adapted to the new position, so the new formula in A1 should sum the two cells at the left of A1, but there are not cells at the left of A1, so the #href error is telling you that.

To do what you want you should paste it like "value". You find that option in the Paste command

Comment: Thanks. I find this option under "paste Special" in excel-2007

Comment: You are welcome. If you have resolved your problem you should flag the answer as accepted to close the question (and make me gain some points :-))